# 'dict' object is not callable wittheout a dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary, maze

hello so i'm having a TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
i'm trying to solve a maze with a graph and so i need to know if we cans pass from a node to another. the "passage" function is doing it :

```
def passage(case1,case2,Lab = Labyrinth):
result = False
for valeur in Lab.dico[case1]:
    if valeur == case2 :
        result = True
return result
```

my main function is (i'm sure everythings work until 'if boucle == 1 :')

````
    for valeur in Labyrinth.dico[noeud] :
        if valeur not in sommet_parcourus :
            sommet_parcourus.append(valeur)
            if valeur[0]-1 == noeud[0]: # deplacement vers le bas
                plus_court_chemin(sup_sommet(Labyrinth,noeud), valeur,sommet_parcourus,2)
            elif valeur[0]+1 == noeud[0]: #deplacement vers le haut
                plus_court_chemin(sup_sommet(Labyrinth,noeud), valeur,sommet_parcourus,2)
            elif valeur[1]-1 == noeud[1]: #deplacement vers la droite 
                plus_court_chemin(sup_sommet(Labyrinth,noeud), valeur,sommet_parcourus,2)
            elif valeur[1]+1 == noeud[1]: #deplacement vers la gauche
                plus_court_chemin(sup_sommet(Labyrinth,noeud), valeur,sommet_parcourus,2)
    if boucle == 1 :
        sommet_a_parcourir = {}
        fin = False
        while fin == False:
            for i in range(len(sommet_parcourus)-1):      
                if passage(sommet_parcourus[i],sommet_parcourus[i+1]) == True:#this line is the one wrong
                    pass
                else :
                    del sommet_parcourus[i]
                    break
        print(sommet_parcourus)```


#sorry i'm french so there's a lot in it
````

Comment: if you are getting an error, post the full error message including the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

I think that what causes you trouble is that you call an index in the dictionary, and this is not allowed in Python.
You can see this here:

```py
.
.
.
if passage(sommet_parcourus[i],sommet_parcourus[i+1]) == True:#this line is the one wrong
.
.
# and here as well
.
.
del sommet_parcourus[i]
```

You can't call a dictionary item by its index. Call it by the key only.
Change your code to refer to the desired value by the key.
Good luck!